# Event listener not triggering?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to push array elements gathered from an input to a HTML table. The event listener is not triggering for some reason, here is the HTML.

```
        <form id="frm1">
      <input id='keyword-input' type="text" placeholder="Keywords"></input>
      <input id="color-input" type="text" placeholder="Color"></input>
      <input id="size-input" type="text" placeholder="Size"></input>
      <input id="profile-input" type="text" placeholder="Profile"></input>
      <input id="proxy-input" type="text" placeholder="Proxy"></input>
      <input id="category-input" type="text" placeholder="Category"></input>
      <input id="tasks-input" type="number" placeholder="# Of Tasks"></input>
      <input id="schedule-input" type="time" placeholder="Schedule Task"></input>
      <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Method"></input>
      <button type="submit" form="frm1" class="add-button" id='addTask'>Add Task</button>
    </form>
```

I have tried moving the listener further down the script, and I have tried embedding it in an onload function, but neither have solved the issue.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('addTask');


submitButton.addEventListener('submit', displayTable);


let taskModel = [{
    taskKeyword : value,
    taskSize : value,
    taskProfile : value
}];


function displayTable(taskModel) {
    var table = document.getElementById('taskTable');

    for (var i = 0; i < taskModel.length; ++i) {
      var tasks = tasks[i];

      var row = document.createElement('tr');

      var properties = ['taskKeyword', 'taskSize', 'taskProfile'];

      for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; ++j) {

        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        cell.innerHTML = taskModel[properties[j]];


        row.appendChild(cell);
      }

      table.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
```

I expected the function to be executed once the 'addTask' button is pressed, but it is not appearing in the dev tools event listener.

Comment: would you please paste the html code too. Hard to diagnore with the JS only

Comment: Simply based on your variable names, if *submit**Button*** indeed is a *<button>*, then it's on its <form> ancestor that you want to listen this submit event.

Comment: HTML has been updated

Comment: May be related: [Button does not submit form](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2018/08/form-submit/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the listener to your `form` instead of the `button`.

From the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit):

> The `submit` event is fired when a form is submitted.
>
> **Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input.**
>
> *Forms are submitted, not buttons.*

---

**Important changes to your code:**

- **No.1:** In your `displayTable` handler function, change the parameter to a different name instead of `taskModel`.
- *Why?* You're trying to use `taskModel` assuming that it holds the task data. However, the actual value of `taskModel` when the function is called is the `event` data. The handler function, by default, when executed is passed the `event object` (that was created when the event/action you are interested in happened) as an argument.
- **No.2:** Change `taskModel[properties[j]]` to `taskModel[0][properties[j]]`
- *Why?* You have to specify the `index` of the `taskModel` when accessing it since you declared it as an array.

```js
var taskForm = document.getElementById('frm1');

taskForm.addEventListener('submit', displayTable);

function displayTable(event) {
  let taskModel = [{
    taskKeyword: document.getElementById('keyword-input').value,
    taskSize: document.getElementById('size-input').value,
    taskProfile: document.getElementById('profile-input').value
  }];
  var table = document.getElementById('taskTable');

  for (var i = 0; i < taskModel.length; ++i) {
    //var tasks = tasks[i];
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var properties = ['taskKeyword', 'taskSize', 'taskProfile'];
    for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; ++j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.innerHTML = taskModel[0][properties[j]]; // You have to specify the index of the taskModel since you declared it as an array
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }

  // added event.preventDefault(); for demo purposes
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  <input id='keyword-input' type="text" placeholder="Keywords"></input>
  <input id="color-input" type="text" placeholder="Color"></input>
  <input id="size-input" type="text" placeholder="Size"></input>
  <input id="profile-input" type="text" placeholder="Profile"></input>
  <input id="proxy-input" type="text" placeholder="Proxy"></input>
  <input id="category-input" type="text" placeholder="Category"></input>
  <input id="tasks-input" type="number" placeholder="# Of Tasks"></input>
  <input id="schedule-input" type="time" placeholder="Schedule Task"></input>
  <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Method"></input>
  <button type="submit" form="frm1" class="add-button" id='addTask'>Add Task</button>
</form>

<table id="taskTable">
</table>
```

*Note: I modified the `taskModel` implementation on this answer for demo purposes.*

Comment: @WaisKamal From the naming convention that he used there's a higher possibility that he's referring to a button instead of a form.

Comment: Better listen for the submit of the <form>, there are other means to submit it than with a click on this button.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me either, I am still not getting the event trigger in my dev tools, or the log in the console.

Comment: If that's the case, better post your html markup so we'll have more idea on what might be causing the issue as Teodor previously mentioned.

Comment: the html has been added, my apologies

Comment: @TomSmith No worries and thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac Thanks for updating your answer. I implemented this into my code but the HTML table is still not updating upon submission of the form. Is there anything else you would suggest trying?

Comment: @TomSmith  First, check if the function is now being called by either console logging it. If yes, the error probably occurs on your `taskModel` or `tasks` implementation. I'm not sure how you are assigning value to your `taskModel`  (Based on your code, where did you get `value`?). Also, notice that I commented out `tasks` since it was causing an error before.